# react router doesn't render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i develop my project with `react-router`.

below is my code.

```
const App2 = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="index">index</Link>
                <Link to="favorite">favorite</Link>
                <Link to="myPage">myPage</Link>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var app = ReactDOM.render (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App2}>
            <Route path="index" component={PhotoFeedWrapper}/>
            <Route path="favorite" component={FavoriteWrapper}/>
            <Route path="myPage" component={MyPageWrapper}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

i think my code right. but, this render empty like below.

```
<div id="app"><!-- react-empty: 1 --></div>
```

there is no script error.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you accessing it? Using `http://localhost/index`? Also, can you post your other components to see if they are correct?

Comment: @WilliamMartins No, i accessing it `http://localhost:8080/contextPath/index`. i don't use it on node. i use it with spring and UMD build. so, i use like that. other component is correct

Comment: It is strange, are your links being rendered?

Comment: @WilliamMartins thank you for your help. i didn't know that uri must match.

Comment: Oh, did it help? :D

Answer (score 1):

`Link` component currently only support absolute path. You have to change to:

```
<Link to="/index">index</Link>
<Link to="/favorite">favorite</Link>
<Link to="/myPage">myPage</Link>
```

Comment: I saw your `Link` set up then I immediately posted this. Then I realize this doesn't answer your original question. But it does fix one other error in your code. :P